# creating n array of objects based on dynamic number

Tags: javascript

I need to create an array based on number which is my limit. So below is my input and this the expected output I am looking out

Input

```
3
```

Expected output

```
[{value: 3, label: 3}, {value: 2, label: 2}, {value: 1, label: 1}, {value: 0, label: 0}]
```

Tried this

```
Array(3).map((_, i) => ({value: i, label: i  }))
```

But this didn't worked, any help is appreciated

Comment: Very close. Please try: `[...Array(n+1)].map((x, i) => ({ value: n-i, label: n-1}));` where `n` is your input number (for example: `3`).

Comment: one doubt if n is 0 then its giving label as -1

Comment: @yousoumar answer is right it handles the n = 0 case also, is there any es6 short for it

Comment: Got it @jsN00b in your above comment label: n - 1 but it should be n - i, i think typo thanks :)

Comment: Typo - guilty as charged. :-). Also serves me a lesson to not type code in comments - an oft-repeated adage by SO pro-members I've read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const n = parseInt(prompt('Enter value for n: ').toString()) ?? 3;

console.log(
  [...Array(n+1)]
  .map(
    (x, i) => ({
      value: n-i,
      label: n-i
    })
  )
);
```

**Explanation**

- Create an array of `n + 1` elements
- Iterate over the array and hold the index as `i`
- For each element, `.map()` an object with props `value` & `label`
- In order to get the sort-order right, use `n - i` as the value for both props

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you could achieve what you want, using a for boucle:

```js
let input = 3;
const result=[]
for(let i = input; i>=0; i--){
  result.push({value:i, label:i})
}
console.log( result)
```

A shorter solution :

```js
let input =3
console.log(Array.from(Array(input+1)).map((_, i) => ({value: i, label: i})).sort((v1, v2)=>v2.value-v1.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Array.from()` like this:

```js
Array.from(Array(3)).map((_, i) => ({value: i, label: i}))
```

Note that this will run from 0 to 2, not 0 to 3 as per your expected output as the length of the array is 3. The easiest way to get the output you expect would be to make it into a function and add 1 to the number supplied to the function, i.e.

```js
const generateArray = number => Array.from(Array(number + 1)).map((_, i) => ({value: i, label: i}))

generateArray(3) // [{value: 0, label: 0}, {value: 1, label: 1}, {value: 2, label: 2}, {value: 3, label: 3}]
```

Comment: No i want to start it from 0

Comment: Both of the above examples do start from 0

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = 3
const answer = []
for(let i = 0; i <= input; i++){
  let obj = {'value': i, 'label': i}
  answer.push(obj)
}

console.log(answer)
```